# Neo4j How to insert csv file?

Tags: node.js, csv, neo4j

I need to insert data using a CSV file in to a Neo4j database.
is there any method possibilities for uploading file or using ftp protocol.
I only saw use http protocol.
plz I am learning now and still a beginer.
[neo4j importing CSV files with cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html)

I an using neo4j-node library for working with Neo4j database with node.js. No use of java.
tx

Comment: You can `ftp://` style URLs as well. It would be good if you refine your question following http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can also do this with local files using the 'file:///<absolute path>' form.